# UIWebView cannot click link

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am pretty sure that I understand how to catch a click on a UIWebView using the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: method, but my webView does not even allow me to click the link.  I am using:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, top, boundsSize.width - 40.0, 400.0f)];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
// add to subview
```

I am loading in an HTML string rather than loading a URL:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:bodyHTML baseURL:nil];
```

Delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSLog(@"Loaded");

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
        NSLog(urlString);
    }

    return YES;

}//end
```

Everytime my webview loads I DO get the "Loaded" in my logs, so I know that the delegate method is getting called.  But I can never click on a link within my UIWebView and have anything happen.  It does not even look like it is allowing a pressed state on the link.  The link is highlighted like a link, just won't allow clicking.

Ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `urlString`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the UIWebView not responding to touch events is most probably this line:

`webView.opaque = NO;`

Try setting opaque to `YES`.

My understanding is that for a view to respond to touch events, that view has to be returned by the call to `hitTest:withEvent:` during the view hierarchy traversal performed  by the event delivery mechanism.

From the `hitTest:withEvent:` [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB):

> This method ignores view objects that are hidden, that have disabled user interaction, or have an alpha level less than 0.01.

### Update

Based on new info: if the UIWebView is embedded in a UIScrollView, quote from the Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Ok. What are the contents of `bodyHTML`? Is your HTML correct? Have you tried opening it in a browser and see if your links work there?

Comment: The contents of bodyHTML is fully valid HTML that I pull from my my website. It looks like it is a subview issue, where one is covering the other.  I place the UIWebview inside a UIView that is when placed as a subview of a UIScrollView.  Apparently this is the issue and I will have to figure out how to change this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if(navigationType==UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```